# Need help solving why my app crashed and getting the H10 error method GET

Tags: node.js, heroku

How to resolve this error, n open heroku app:

2018-12-26T22:50:56.636727+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=young-springs-33489.herokuapp.com request_id=cdc49a54-7667-4406-bb48-9347699e2eb3 fwd="24.216.55.31" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: That's an error message from Heroku indicating that something in the software you installed crashed - bad enough that it's preventing the app from starting.

You should be able to check your logs (e.g. via heroku logs command, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) and find more details, depending on the software you are using.  Depending on the stack you are using, you can go from there...

Comment: I have used heroku logs --tail to me whats going on and thats the message i get.

Comment: Is everything in your `package.json` file correct? Do you have all the dependencies in that file that your app requires?

Comment: {
  "name": "project-2-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "event-stream": "^3.3.5",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "hbs": "~4.0.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.8",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.6",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4"
  }
}

Comment: https://github.com/Justint1234/Project-2-app if you would like a better look at what im dealing with here is the link to the project.